# How to find similar pattern along with missing entities over a big data?

Tags: python, pattern-matching, bigdata, data-mining, data-science

I want to search for certain kind of pattern data over the list of data along with its missing entities. 
For example I have a user data of the following:

```
User 1: 123 254 225 367 125 745 587
User 2: 333 444 225 123 254
User 3: 777 451 225 745 254 458
User 4: 111 222 333 444 555 666 777 888
```

And I have a search pattern of:

```
254 225 125 587 745
```

I need to search this pattern over the user data regardless of their order of occurrence and provide results as following:

```
User 1: 
User 2: 125 587 745
User 3: 125 587
User 4: 254 225 125 587 745
```

The numbers in the result denotes missing entities for the pattern.

I tried implementing Apriori and FP-Growth algorithm to find the pattern, but it didn't work as expected. Also the data size is very big, it just took too long even to create pattern graph or pattern tree. The above data is just a sample data. I need to perform this analysis over several thousands user data.

What can be the best approach to get this done?

Comment: What type is the input data? Is it a dict, a string, a list...?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I might do it in pure Python.

Time complexity is `O(um+n)`, where `m` is the size of the search pattern, `u` is the number of users in the input dict, and `n` is the size of the input dict. For relatively small search patterns as described in the problem definition, this method is effectively `O(n)`.

```
# Inputs
userDict = {
  'User 1': [123, 254, 225, 367, 125, 745, 587],
  'User 2': [333, 444, 225, 123, 254],
  'User 3': [777, 451, 225, 745, 254, 458],
  'User 4': [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888]
}

filterList = [254, 225, 125, 587, 745]

# Filter a dictionary of lists based on a search pattern
# Returns for each value in the dictionary, the elements from the search pattern
# which were not found in the list
#
def filterLists(inputDict, filterList):
  # Use a Set for the O(1) lookup
  filterSet = set(filterList)
  res = {}
  for key, vals in inputDict.items():
    # Creating a Set from a list of size n is O(n)
    # Set difference is O(size of the leftmost set)
    # Assuming the search pattern is shorter than the average User list,
    # this gives us effectively O(n)
    res[key] = list(filterSet - set(vals))
  return res

print(filterLists(userDict, filterList))
```

Basically, don't overthink it, the Apriori and FP-Growth algorithms are for a different class of problems to this. You are basically implementing a filter or sieve here, and since your inputs aren't structured or ordered you really can't get around reading every integer at least once, meaning you can't get any faster than O(n).

So in my code, I simply do a couple of set operations in O(n) time and return the output. No need for more complex or clever representations. You can do better than my code with a little tweaking, but not asymptotically better in the general case.

---

Note also that if you are working with big data, you probably want to use something like Spark instead. The same thing could be done elegantly with a bit of Scala code and you'd have something that would parallelize well across a cluster for pretty much arbitrary sized datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me (but it may not be the best performing solution):

I assume you can somehow cast your input into a `dict` of the form:

```
d = {'User 1': [123, 254, 225, 367, 125, 745, 587],
     'User 2': [333, 444, 225, 123 ,254], ...}
```

Now, with the given pattern

```
pattern = [254, 225, 125, 587, 745]
```

lets produce a second dict which holds the output:

```
d_out = {}
for key in d.keys():
    d_out[key] = []
    for value in pattern:
        d_out[key].append(value in d[key])
```

The performance maybe not optimal if your pattern list is big (because of the loop), it should be more or less independent of the size of the user data though.

Now I take `pattern` as a mask and use a custom version of the `itertools.compress` function to get the result (the function produced an error on my machine and I could not use it directly, sorry):

```
for key in d.keys():
    print(key, [data for data, mask in zip(pattern, d_out[key]) if not mask])
```

which yields the output:

```
User 1 []
User 2 [125, 587, 745]
```

Maybe this is something you can start from.

Comment: This should work, but as you mention the performance is not optimal since the first loop will run in O(m*n) time (m being the pattern length and n being the size of the input). You could speed it up a lot by simply turning d[key] into a set before the inner loop since the 'in' operator is O(1) on sets.

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary of users and a check list this can be accomplished using *dictionary comprehension*

```
users = {
  'User 1': [123, 254, 225, 367, 125, 745, 587],
  'User 2': [333, 444, 225, 123, 254],
  'User 3': [777, 451, 225, 745, 254, 458],
  'User 4': [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888]
}

check = [254, 225, 125, 587, 745]
res = {k: [i for i in check if i not in users[k]] for k in users}
```

> ```
> {'User 1': [], 'User 2': [125, 587, 745], 'User 3': [125, 587], 'User 4': [254, 225, 125, 587, 745]}
> ```

Comment: Nice and clean, but it’s not very performant. The `in` operator on lists is linear time complexity, resulting in a time complexity for the list comprehension of O(m*n).

Comment: @JensRoland If I pull the list comprehension list out of the dictionary comprehension does it increase speed?